# iOS long-running background timer with "location" background mode

Tags: ios, background

I want to implement long-running background timer which sends user's location to server periodically.

To do this, I set `location` mode for `UIBackgroundModes`, and call `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` when the application goes to background.
And for `CLLocationManager`, I use `startUpdatingLocation` method (don't want to use significant change, because I need high precision location).

But around 26minutes after the app goes to background, it stops to send location to the server. But the app isn't crashed, so after I bring the app to foreground, it can resume its timer.

26minutes is from experiments, with iOS 6.1, iPhone 5.

Here are some questions,

1. I can't understand why it suspends after 26mins not 10mins, which is known as time limit for background task.
2. Before 16mins, `backgroundTimeRemaining` methods returns double max value. But after 16mins, it decreases from `600`, so it suspends the background task after 10mins.

I already tried to call `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` inside of expiration handler, but no use.

If there's anyone who has a clue for this problem, will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution? This happened to me to... :(

Answer (score 6):

https://github.com/voyage11/Location

Use this code.you can set time interval you want to call it. I have tried many codes, but i found this as most accurate and least battery issue.This is also awesome for background location service. :)

Comment: Alight. Looks promising. I'll try this. Thank you

Comment: @NikitaKhandelwal Does apple accept app with this approach?

Comment: @venky, I see no reason Apple would reject it.

Comment: Its working, but  when app in background and device screen off, then its not updating to server.

Answer (score -1):

if you have set `UIBackgroundModes` successfully，the App can run a long time in the background while you are moving. But, if you stop moving for over 10 minutes（maybe more）， the App will be suspended by the system. Your App will be awake if the location updates，but this awake time will be very short，so you must cal
`beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` method to handle location update.